# Add new element to Laravel collection object inside each element

Tags: php, laravel

I would like to add new element to each existing element in Laravel object collection in Laravel. My object is something like this,

```
object(Illuminate\Support\Collection)#178 (1) {
  ["items":protected]=>
  array(10) {
    [0]=>
    object(stdClass)#175 (4) {
      ["fname"]=>
      string(6) "xxx"
      ["lname"]=>
      string(5) "xxx"
      ["data2"]=>
      string(3) "xxx"
      ["callid"]=>
      string(17) "xxx"
    }
    [1]=>
    object(stdClass)#179 (4) {
      ["fname"]=>
      string(6) "xxx"
      ["lname"]=>
      string(5) "xxx"
      ["data2"]=>
      string(2) "62"
      ["callid"]=>
      string(17) "xxx"
    }
}
```

So I need to add something like   ["phonenumber"]=>string(17) "xxx" to each block. Then object looks like this,

```
object(Illuminate\Support\Collection)#178 (1) {
      ["items":protected]=>
      array(10) {
        [0]=>
        object(stdClass)#175 (4) {
          ["fname"]=>
          string(6) "xxx"
          ["lname"]=>
          string(5) "xxx"
          ["data2"]=>
          string(3) "xxx"
          ["callid"]=>
          string(17) "xxx"
         ["phonenumber"]=>
          string(17) "xxx"
        }
        [1]=>
        object(stdClass)#179 (4) {
          ["fname"]=>
          string(6) "xxx"
          ["lname"]=>
          string(5) "xxx"
          ["data2"]=>
          string(2) "62"
          ["callid"]=>
          string(17) "xxx"
          ["phonenumber"]=>
          string(17) "xxx"
        }
    }
```

My code is something like this

```
     $resultsInCalls....    
       foreach ($resultsInCalls as $key=>$value) {

                $resultsUserNumber =  DB::table('qlog')
                ->select('data2')
                ->where('event', '=', 'ENTERQUEUE')
                ->where('callid', '=', $value->callid)
                ->get();  


               $resultsInCalls->push('phoneNumber', $resultsUserNumber['0']->data2);

}
```

But above code adds somthing like this instead expected result,

```
 [5]=>
    string(11) "phoneNumber"
 [6]=>
    string(11) "phoneNumber"
 [7]=>
    string(11) "phoneNumber"
 [8]=>
    string(11) "phoneNumber"
 [9]=>
    string(11) "phoneNumber"
```

How do I get expected result. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loop the collection using each

```
$resultsInCalls = $resultsInCalls->each(function ($item, $key) {
     $resultsUserNumber =  DB::table('qlog')
                ->select('data2')
                ->where('event', '=', 'ENTERQUEUE')
                ->where('callid', '=', $item->callid)
                ->get();  
               $item->phoneNumber = $resultsUserNumber['0']->data2;
});
```

A better way will be using a relationship or a join